# cell tower location for CDMA android phone using getBaseStationLatitude()/Longitude()

Tags: java, android, cdma

I'm developing an android app for CDMA phones that will gather the latitude/longitude of the cell tower they are connected to.

First: is this even possible?

Second: I've looked at previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409696/why-getbasestationlatitude-keeps-returning-the-integer-max-value-unknown) where it says to simply add "CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();" but it didn't have any effect. Here's the portion of code where I'm trying to retrieve the locations...

```
CdmaCellLocation CdmaLocation = (CdmaCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
int Longitude = CdmaLocation.getBaseStationLongitude();
int Latitude = CdmaLocation.getBaseStationLatitude();
```

Looking at [the code](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/telephony/java/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.java.shtml) for the CdmaCellLocation class reveals that those values are defaulted to Integer.MAX_VALUE, but how do you actually set the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Before you cast `getCellLocation` to `CdmaCellLocation`, check your phoneType with `telephonyManager.getPhoneType()`, only cast it to Cdma if `telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA`. If you get `TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM` you should cast it to `GsmCellLocation`. I believe you get weird integer because the phone type is not cdma.

Comment: I just tried adding that to the code and unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I probably should have mentioned that I'm already testing on a CDMA phone. Thanks for the quick response though

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `PhoneStateListener`  with `LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION` and the corresponding callback function `onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation)` and `LISTEN_CELL_INFO` with callback function `onCellInfoChanged(List)` and possibly `LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGHTS` with callback `onSignalStrengthsChanged(Signal Strength)`

to quit getting change notification from the PhoneStateListener use `LISTEN_NONE`

http://www.truiton.com/2014/08/android-phonestatelistener-example/

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html